# Opencart 3.0 -- Display All Products from Category by ID on Category Page

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I switched over to Opencart 3.0.. Not to fond of the .tpl to .twig changes.

Anyways, I have been trying, to no avail, to display all products from a particular category on another category page.

I found this foreach loop:

`{% for product in products %}`

Which I imagine reads

`<?php foreach ($products as $product) { //do something } ?>`

I tried adding the Loop to the path:

`catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/category.twig`

but it only shows the products from the current category page id I am currently on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is likely due to the controller only retrieving products that relate to the category id that is set in the `GET` request. You might need to add another array for the new products you wish to display and then duplicate that loop e.g. `{% for product in products2 %}` are you familiar with the MVC structure in OC?

Comment: I'm a little familiar, Model gets the data, while controller passes it to the view... My problem is deciphering what I can edit without messing up something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally bad practise on OC to edit the files directly, rather look at OCMOD or VQMOD to make runtime changes but not edit the core file. Granted this may be  an additional complication right now.

If you look at the category.php file in the `/catalog/controller/product/` folder around line 150, you'll see these lines of code:

```
$data['products'] = array();

$filter_data = array(
    'filter_category_id' => $category_id,
    'filter_filter'      => $filter,
    'sort'               => $sort,
    'order'              => $order,
    'start'              => ($page - 1) * $limit,
    'limit'              => $limit
);

$product_total = $this->model_catalog_product->getTotalProducts($filter_data);

$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
```

What you need to do is create a new `$filter_data` variable with your requisite filters, you can just have the category ID if that's all you need.

Look at the line below:

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);
```

It's calling the method `getProducts` which is located in the model `CatalogCategory` (`/catalog/model/product.php`) this method will build a `SQL` query based on the filters passed to the method and return an associative array with the results (hence the aptly named `$results` variable).

The controller file we first looked at then iterates through these `$results` and stores the values in `$data['products']`.

Putting this together, you can try the following:

```
$data['products2'] = array();

$new_filter_data = array(
    'filter_category_id' => 13 // or any relevant ID
);

$results2 = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($new_filter_data);
```

This isn't a complete solution as the controller file continues to resize images, get reviews etc. So you'll need to adjust this according to what your needs are and play around a little.

Just make sure you're working on a local copy of the site!

Comment: This makes so much since! I will try it--and i'll play around getting it to run through an ocmod thanks much!

Comment: You're welcome @JCBiggar , let me know if there are any issues, it's untested but should work!